# How can I use C++11 features like delegating constructors in Visual C++ November 2012 CTP?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, constructor, visual-studio-2012

I installed visual c++ November 2012 CTP but it seems i do something wrong because i still can't use *delegating constructors*

1. I set the Platform Toolset to : Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012)
2. This is my code:

   ```
   #pragma once

   #include<string>

   class Hero
   {
   private:
       long id;
       std::string name;
       int level;
       static long currentId;
       Hero(const Hero &hero); //disable copy constructor
       Hero& operator =(const Hero &hero); //disable assign operator
   public:
       Hero();
       Hero(std::string name, int level);
       long GetId() const { return this->id; }
       std::string GetName() const { return this->name; }
       int GetLevel() const { return this->level; }
       void SetName(std::string name);
       void SetLevel(int level);
   };
   ```

PS: Any tips regarding to c++11 and visual studio 2012 are more then welcomed. Thanks.

LE: This is the implementation file:

```
#include"Hero.h"

long Hero::currentId = 0;

Hero::Hero(std::string name, int level):name(name), level(level), id(++currentId) 
{

}

Hero::Hero():Hero("", 0)
{

}

void Hero::SetName(const std::string &name) 
{
    this->name = name; 
}

void Hero::SetLevel(const int &level) 
{
    this->level = level; 
}
```

I get the following error message on the parameterless constructor:
"Hero" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Hero"

Comment: Delegating constructors are in the CTP, I don't see explicitly deleted member functions listed.  Work in process, surely.  Post feedback to connect.microsoft.com, put [Codename Milan] in the title.

Comment: Post the error messages.

Comment: "NOT WORKING" is insufficient feedback. _Tell us what you see_.

Comment: Okay then it does look like delegating constructors are not "enabled" here for you for whatever reason.

Comment: Is there anything i should set other than Platform Toolset?

Comment: I just tested it with `Visual c++ November 2012 CTP` and it compiles. Are you sure the error is not just with intellisense? Also your signatures for `SetName` and `SetLevel` are different in the header and cpp file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message you quote is being reported by IntelliSense, which does not yet support the new C++11 language features.  Note that the full text of the error message reads (emphasis mine):

> **IntelliSense**: "Hero" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Hero"

[The announcement for the November CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx) states (emphasis mine):

> While a new Platform Toolset is provided for convenience of integrating the compiler as part of the Visual Studio 2012 build environment, **the VS 2012 IDE, Intellisense, debugger, static analysis, and other tools remain essentially unchanged and do not yet provide support for these new C++11 features.**

The compiler, which *is* updated by the November CTP, rejects the code with the following errors:

```
error C2511: 'void Hero::SetName(const std::string &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Hero'
    c:\jm\scratch\test.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'Hero'
error C2511: 'void Hero::SetLevel(const int &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Hero'
    c:\jm\scratch\test.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'Hero'
```

These errors are expected because your code is ill-formed (the parameters of `SetLevel` and `SetName` are passed by value in their inline declarations, and by reference in their definitions).  When these errors are fixed, the compiler accepts your code.