# Is there a way to use delegating constructors in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

Looking through the new features of C++11, delegating constructors seems like they would be particular useful in my situation.

Unfortunately, I need to use Visual Studio. The project I am working on has a several month deadline and using experimental/broken compilers doesn't concern me. Is there a version of Visual C++ that can will let me do constructor delegation?

See http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting

Comment: Your question is slightly confused - do not mix up the inheritance of constructors with the C++11 feature _delegating constructors_. I have removed your link to the former, since you are in fact asking about the latter.

Comment: Almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416574/how-can-i-use-c11-features-like-delegating-constructors-in-visual-c-november

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a beta version of the compiler that supports delegating constructors - the [Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515).

Comment: [Careful, though](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14431812/560648): `the VS 2012 IDE, Intellisense, debugger, static analysis, and other tools remain essentially unchanged and do not yet provide support for these new C++11 features.`

Comment: Was this released as update 1? I can't seem to get it to take up my code. How do we actually get it to compile the code? Pass it in as a textfile?

Comment: @Mikhail This is going to be released as update 2. For now, it is just a CTP.

Comment: It can be added as a compiler to VS. See info at the download page.

Comment: It is not part of any "Update" nor will it ever be. The CTP stands as it is and needs to be installed _in addition_ to the newest update.

However, VS2013 supports all of the CTP features and more.

Answer (score 3):

In the meanwhile, try

```
#define INHERIT_CONSTRUCTOR(BaseName,DerivedName) template <class... Args> DerivedName(Args&&... args) : BaseName(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
```

Comment: This looks straight forward enough. Compact solution. I'm trying it out now. *IntelliSense* is happy. I haven't compiled yet (and won't for a while--code is not nearly ripe enough for that), won'. There must be some gotcha in there somewhere, haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've successfully installed the CTP via the link given above by Karel Petranek, just create any old C++ project.

Then, under the project's 'Property Pages > Configuration Properties > General > Platform Toolset', choose "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012)".

That's all. Now you have access to [these additional C++ compiler features in VS2012](http://aka.ms/vc-ctp-tour).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install CTP anymore.
[Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) will support delegating constructors and you can try the Preview version which is available by now.