# C++11's Delegating Constructors in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I am trying to use delegating constructors in Visual Studio 2012. The following code compiles in Xcode 4.6 but not in Visual Studio 2012:

In the .h file

```
class ErrorReportDlg : public QDialog
{

public:
    ErrorReportDlg(OwlExceptionPtr ex, QWidget *parent);
    ErrorReportDlg(QWidget *parent);

    virtual ~ErrorReportDlg();
}
```

In the .cpp file

```
// FWIW, OwlExceptionPtr is 
// typdef boost::shared_ptr<OwlException> OwlExceptionPtr

ErrorReportDlg::ErrorReportDlg(OwlExceptionPtr ex, QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent),
    _error(ex)
{
    // stuff
}

ErrorReportDlg::ErrorReportDlg(QWidget *parent)
    : ErrorReportDlg(OwlExceptionPtr(), parent) // <--- error here
{
    // do nothing
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> error C2437: 'ErrorReportDlg' : already initialized

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Try Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 6):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx), VS 2012 doesn't support delegating constructors out of the box.

You get delegating constructors (and a bunch of other C++11 features) when you install the [November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) (Compiler Technical Preview). After installing, switch your project to use the CTP as its toolset (via `Project properties`), and you're set.

Comment: Thank you, this link had me confused: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432802/is-there-a-way-to-use-delegating-constructors-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: @Addy You never mentioned in the question whether you have the CTP installed. Do you? And if so, are you using it as your toolset?

Comment: I did not have it set as my toolset. Once I did that, it worked. Now to figure out how to make that my toolset through CMake. Thank you!

Comment: @Addy `cmake ... -T "the string VS uses to identify the toolset" ...`. Requires CMake 2.8.11 or later.