# Implementation of C++11 delegating constructors feature results in several warnings

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have tried to implement the C++11 feature (I've used this answer as a reference [Can I call a constructor from another constructor (do constructor chaining) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/c-call-constructor-from-constructor)).  Obviously, I've done it wrong but I don't understand why.

I get several warnings in the following piece of code:

- Member `_output` was not initialized in this constructor
- Member `_protocol_scanner` was not initialized in this constructor
- Member `_state` was not initialized in this constructor
- Member `_source` was not initialized in this constructor

This is the code:

```
class UartScanner {
public:
    UartScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source, periph::IStreamDevice *output);
    UartScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source);
    ~UartScanner();

private:
typedef enum
{
    WAITING_SYNC,
    WAITING_UBLOX_MSG,
    WAITING_NOVATEL_MSG
} states_t;

    periph::IStreamDevice *_source;
    periph::IStreamDevice *_output;
    ProtocolScanner *_protocol_scanner;
    states_t _state;
};

UartScanner::UartScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source, IStreamDevice *output):
    _source(source),
    _output(output),
    _state(WAITING_SYNC)
{
    _protocol_scanner = new ProtocolScanner(source,output);
}

UartScanner::UartScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source): UartScanner(source,0) 
{
}

class IStreamDevice {
public:
    virtual ~IStreamDevice() {}
    virtual uint32_t read(uint8_t* data, uint32_t size) = 0;
    virtual uint32_t write(const uint8_t* data, uint32_t size) = 0;
};
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Don't use leading underscores in member names. Leading underscores are reserved for standard library implementation.

Comment: That only applies to names in the global namespace, @Snps; leading underscores in member names, as we have here, are fine.

Comment: @RobKennedy As long as they are followed by a digit or lowercase letter.

Comment: @arne I'n using GCC ARM Embedded 4.7. I have to follow this naming convention. We don't use STL, so it's not a problem.

Comment: @RobKennedy It's allowed if the underscore is not followed by an uppercase letter, but why make it a cognitive challenge everytime? It's easier to just stay away from leading underscores. Also it's ugly and obfuscating.

Comment: @Snps No, it's beautiful and helps reading the code.

Comment: @PetrBudnik It gives me headaches when reading codes with leading underscores. I keep waiting for it to disappear and be gone forever.

Comment: [OT]: you may use `nullptr` instead of `0`.

Comment: I appreciate that broadening the rule makes it easier to remember and follow, @Snps, but you shouldn't then repeat your broadened rule as though it's the real rule that everyone must follow. Your previous comment wrongly suggests that *all* leading-underscore names are reserved when that's not really true.

Comment: Not reproducible here with gcc 4.7.3 or clang 3.1 (cygwin). Can you post an SSCCE?

Comment: @AliAlamiri Let's focus on the issue ;-) P.S. I don't like this convention, though. It's the rules I just need to follow.

Comment: @enter_the_bot It'd be good if you specified compiler and compilation flags...

Comment: @enter_the_bot are you actually getting compiler errors or are they from the IDE !?

Comment: @DieterLücking these are warnings. Not errors! I use only -Wall flag.

Comment: @enter_the_bot then please provide us with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), including full compiler settings. We will try to reproduce the warnings then. For the `_protocol_scanner` it's right, since you assign to it but don't *initialize* it in the implementing constructor.

Comment: Why not just provide `0` as a default value for the `output` parameter in your first constructor, and just eliminate the second one?

Comment: @twalberg I wanted to use something new and get it to work!

Comment: @ArneMertz but _output, _source and _state are initialized. What's the deal?

Comment: The answer is *probably* that whatever compiler you're using doesn't yet fully implement constructor delegation. However, by continuing to ignore the multiple questions about your compilation environment, it's impossible to confirm that.

Comment: @enter_the_bot "We don't use STL, so it's not a problem" on the contrary, "_If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by
this Clause, its behavior is undefined...Each name that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use. Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace._"

Your naming is fine because the names aren't in global NS, not because you aren't using STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a look at your code and I changed a couple of things. I have created a file named Test1.hpp and put your code in it. The following code compiled correctly with GCC 4.7 and Clang 3.3 with the -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors attributes. Let's see what's the contain of the HPP file.

```
#ifndef TEST1_HPP
#define TEST1_HPP
// Some inclusions here ...
namespace periph
{
   class IStreamDevice{ // Something here... };
}

class ProtocolScanner {
    public:
       ProtocolScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source, periph::IStreamDevice *output) 
          : _source(source), _output(output) { }

    private:
       periph::IStreamDevice *_source;
       periph::IStreamDevice *_output;
};


class UartScanner {
    public:
        UartScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source, periph::IStreamDevice *output)
          : _source(source), _output(output), _protocol_scanner(new ProtocolScanner(source,output)), _state(states_t::WAITING_SYNC) { }

        UartScanner(periph::IStreamDevice *source) 
          : UartScanner(source, nullptr) { }

        ~UartScanner() { } // I suppose that something is done in the destructor.

    private:
        enum class states_t : uint8_t {
            WAITING_SYNC,
            WAITING_UBLOX_MSG,
            WAITING_NOVATEL_MSG
        };

        periph::IStreamDevice *_source;
        periph::IStreamDevice *_output;
        ProtocolScanner *_protocol_scanner;
        states_t _state;
};

class IStreamDevice {
    public:
        virtual ~IStreamDevice() {}
        virtual uint32_t read(uint8_t* data, uint32_t size) = 0;
        virtual uint32_t write(const uint8_t* data, uint32_t size) = 0;
};

#endif
```

Notice that I added a namespace and some other classes you used. Since I don't know their definition, I let them empty to make that working. Now, let's review this code.

In C++11, if you want to initialize a pointer to NULL, I suggest you to use the `nullptr` keyword to do the job. [This answer about nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr) should help you to understand.

I also replace the following code

```
typedef enum
{
    WAITING_SYNC,
    WAITING_UBLOX_MSG,
    WAITING_NOVATEL_MSG
} states_t;
```

By the this one (strongly typed enum since C++11)

```
enum class states_t : uint8_t {
    WAITING_SYNC,
    WAITING_UBLOX_MSG,
    WAITING_NOVATEL_MSG
};
```

[A short explanation of the enum class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Strongly_typed_enumerations)

About the delegating constructor, it seems to be correct. It should be used only in constructor initializer list like you did. If this was the problem, maybe the compiler you use doesn't let you use the delegating constructor. If you are using Visual C++, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432802/is-there-a-way-to-use-delegating-constructors-in-visual-studio-2012) should help you. With GCC 4.7 and higher and clang 3.1 and higher, I'm sure it's working.

Hope that helps you.