# Delegating class constructors in C++ using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, class, c++11, delegation

I try to delegate a class constructor in Qt 5.4.0 using C++. The problematic code looks as follows:

```
//.h
class A : public QObject
{

public:
  A(QObject *parent = 0) : A(10, parent) {};   <--COMPILER ERROR
  A(int x, QObject *parent = 0);
  ...
};

//.cpp
A::A(int x, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  do_something();
}
```

The compiler claims that the element initialization 'A' is neither Basis nor Element. Isn't this supported? If so, what causes this error?

Comment: What compiler are you using? This feature is likely not supported by yours.

Comment: This requires C++11 support. Works fine on g++ v4.8.3.

Comment: Also, which flags are you using? Even if it is supported, you likely need to add a c+11 flag (`-std=c++11` for gcc).

Comment: @anderas I am using MSCV 11

Comment: @user3482407 Then my answer applies: It is not supported in that version.

Comment: @Armaghast added CONFIG += c++11 to my .pro file

Comment: This has nothing to do with Qt, and is a clear dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor delegation is a C++11 feature that is not supported by all compilers yet. Chances are that it does not work if you are using a Visual Studio compiler (or an old GCC).

See for example this question, with answers stating that it is not even fully supported in VS2012: [Is there a way to use delegating constructors in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432802/is-there-a-way-to-use-delegating-constructors-in-visual-studio-2012)

For reference, here you can find all features that are supported by the respective MSVC versions (delegating Constructors is mentioned as not supported on MSVC11): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx